# Numpy select rows based on condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I want to remove rows from a two dimensional `numpy` array using a condition on the values of the first row.

I am able to do this with regular python using two loops, but I would like to do it more efficiently with numpy, e.g. with `numpy.where`

I have been trying various things with `numpy.where` and `numpy.delete` but I struggle with applying a condition to the first column only.

Here is an example where I only want to keep the rows where the first value of each row is 6.

Input:

```
[[0,4],
 [0,5],
 [3,5],
 [6,8],
 [9,1],
 [6,1]]
```

Output:

```
[[6,8],
 [6,1]]
```

Comment: You just need to use [2D indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). `arr = arr[arr[:,0] == 6]`

Comment: Thanks, that is even short than using numpy.where

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use a boolean mask:

```
mask = (z[:, 0] == 6)
z[mask, :]
```

This is much more efficient than `np.where` because you can use the boolean mask directly, without having the overhead of converting it to an array of indices first.

One liner:

```
z[z[:, 0] == 6, :]
```

Comment: We can make it even more simple one liner, as without ":" it means just the row: z=z[z[:,0]==6]

Answer (score 7):

Program:

```
import numpy as np
np_array = np.array([[0,4],[0,5],[3,5],[6,8],[9,1],[6,1]])
rows=np.where(np_array[:,0]==6)
print(np_array[rows])
```

Output:

```
[[6 8]
 [6 1]]
```

And If You Want to Get Into 2d List
use

```
np_array[rows].tolist()
```

Output of 2d List

```
[[6, 8], [6, 1]]
```