# Numpy: Selecting Rows based on Multiple Conditions on Some of its Elements

Tags: python-3.x, linux, numpy, centos8

I believe this is not a duplicate question, although there are questions that are fairly close to this one on the website. I would like to isolate a row from a `numpy` list given a set of conditions for some of its elements. Here is an example, consider the array `Z`:

```
>>> Z = [[1,0,3,4], [1,1,3,6], [1,2,3,9], [1,3,4,0], [2,1,4,5]]
>>> Z = np.array(Z)
>>> Z
array([[1, 0, 3, 4],
       [1, 1, 3, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 9],
       [1, 3, 4, 0],
       [2, 1, 4, 5]])
```

and say I would like to isolate the row whose first and second element are both `1`. The command that executes that should output the row

```
np.array([[1, 1, 3, 6]])
```

However, if I follow [`this popular question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58079075/numpy-select-rows-based-on-condition?noredirect=1&lq=1), and make an intuitive extension, such as:

```
Z[Z[:,0] == 1 & Z[:,1] == 1, :]
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Is there any quick fix to that? I do not want to iterate over my list. I was wondering if there is a quick "numpy" way for it.

Comment: Actually, I just figured out a simple solution, one could do:

`mask1 = (Z[:,0] == 1);`

`mask2 = (Z[:,1] == 1);`

`sel = np.logical_and(mask1, mask2);`

The numpy array `sel` contains the rows of `Z` where both of the conditions are true. Then, I can do:

`index = np.where(sel == 1)[0][0]`

and `index` is then the index of interest. Anyways, I would still like to see if there is any more elegant solution to this :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elegant is [`np.equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html)

```
Z[np.equal(Z[:, [0,1]], 1).all(axis=1)]
```

Or:

```
Z[np.equal(Z[:,0], 1) & np.equal(Z[:,1], 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

More simple

```
print (Z[(Z[:,0]==1)&(Z[:,1]==1)])
or
print (Z[(Z[:,0]==1)&(Z[:,1]==1),:])
```

You got
[[1 1 3 6]]