# Can I access data in Nx3 Matrix for other column with specific value

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multiple-columns

Say I have

```py
data=np.array([[30,0.109,1],
               [25,0.517,2],
               [22,0.174,1],
               [35,0.812,3],
               [45,0.215,4],
               [40,0.111,4],
               [50,0.095,4]])
```

Doing

```py
A = data1[:,2]
print(A)
```

Will give me

```
[1. 2. 1. 3. 4. 4. 4.]
```

Is there a command so I can get the values from other columns (1 or 2) if column 3 has a value of 4
In my mind it would look like this
B=data[:,1,[2]=4]
So B should print out
[0.812, 0.215, 0.111]

Is this possible?
The reason I need it is for graphical display. The number in column 3 corresponds to a type of bacteria (I.e. all 4's are the same bacteria), from which I need to plot the other values "bound" to that type of bacteria.

Hope its possible, and all the best

Comment: Unfortunately not for me, it prints out exactly the same as print(data[[:, [0,1]])

Comment: the output should be `array([0.215, 0.111, 0.095])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy select rows based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58079075/numpy-select-rows-based-on-condition)

Comment: what is `data1` in the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use boolean indexing:

```py
out = data[data[:, 2]==4, 1]
```

Output:

```
array([0.215, 0.111, 0.095])
```